# Google cloud build - provide assets to docker build step

Tags: google-cloud-build

I'm trying to combine two examples from the Google Cloud Build documentation

[This example where a container is built using a yaml file](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-build#build_using_a_build_config_file)

[And this example where a persistent volume is used](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config#volumes)

My scenario is simple, the first step in my build produces some assets I'd like to bundle into a Docker image built in a subsequent step. However, since the [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) command is [relative to the build directory of the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012495/docker-copy-from-ubuntu-absolute-path/47012599#47012599), I'm unable to determine how to reference the assets from the first step inside the Dockerfile used for the second step.

Comment: If you solved your won question please mark it as correct, if you are missing something please edit the question with the updated code so we can help you better

Comment: Hi @Edgardo, this is a "Q&A style" post. You have to wait 2 days to accept your own answer. I will do so just as soon as I can ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are potentially multiple ways to solve this problem, but the easiest way I've found is to use the [`docker` cloud builder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/docker) and run an `sh` script (since Bash is not included in the docker image).

In this example, we build on the examples from the question, producing an asset `file` in the first build step, then using it inside the `Dockerfile` of the second step.

### cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  volumes:
  - name: 'vol1'
    path: '/persistent_volume'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
  - '-c'
  - |
        echo "Hello, world!" > /persistent_volume/file
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  entrypoint: 'sh'
  volumes:
  - name: 'vol1'
    path: '/persistent_volume'
  args: [ 'docker-build.sh' ]
  env:
    - 'PROJECT=$PROJECT_ID'
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/quickstart-image'
```

### docker-build.sh

```
#/bin/sh
cp -R /persistent_volume .
docker build -t gcr.io/$PROJECT/quickstart-image .
```